# What is this succulent with tiny triangular leaves and what care does it need?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, succulents

I've got this cute little succulent with thin stems and juicy triangular leaves. I noticed that the top leaves started getting dry, so it's obviously not very happy with my care.

If you know the name please let me know or any tips on growing it would be highly appreciated as well.

[image]

Comment: I think it is "Crassula Tom Thumb." What a beautiful plant(touchwood). I would like to have one but I am more likely to destroy it. I am no expert. So wait for the experts.

Comment: Find a wider than tall clay pot for this guy.  Not much bigger than the diameter of this pot.  Drainage hole, no rock or gravel at the bottom.  Very little water and little fertilizer and it will thrive...decent light.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely a Crassula species. These are beautiful, with heart shaped leaves. It is one of the easiest of succulents (and even plants, in general) to take care of and propagate. They also sometimes have understated, yet beautiful flowers during spring/summer.

From the image, it is hard to tell what is going on. If you can take a better close up, we may be able to tell whether it is disease or just over watering, or crowding, given your plant appears to have grown quite well right now.

You could take some pictures, and then, we may be able to tell what is going on.

From this photo, it still appears the plant is quite healthy and if you cut off the dying stem heads here and there, maybe repot it to allow more room to grow, or add very diluted plant food, you might do just fine.

You should also make sure you are not over-watering the plant. The top soil needs to become dry in between watering turns.